# Text in Entry widget going out of view

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an entry widget as such:

```
...

entry1=Entry(frame1,font=("Verdana",10),width=20)
entry1.grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan=2,pady=10,padx=10,ipday=5)
```

and when I type a long string within in,
it crops out the last letter such that I can't even bring it into view using the right arrow key
[image]
(12039201901--71230110)

but if I add one more character then I can use the right arrow key to bring it into view

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: It is due to using dynamic width font, try using monospaced font instead.

Comment: @acw1668 you mean set `font='TkFixedFont'`?

Comment: Better specify existing monospaced font in your platform/OS, like `Courier`.

Comment: You've specified a width of 20, but you have 21 characters. Have you tried setting the width to 21?

Comment: @BryanOakley same problem

Comment: @acw1668 on changing the font it does look far better, but still doesn't completely solve the problem

Comment: Well, yes, if you put more text in the widget than will fit, some characters must get chopped off.

Comment: @BryanOakley getting chopped off isn't the problem, you can use the arrow keys to bring them into view but when it's only a single character getting chopped off the right arrow key doesn't bring it into view

Comment: I don't have the issue if a monospaced font is used.

Comment: @acw1668 then i think you should post it as a solution, I doubt there's any better way